# Flutter package: google_mobile_ads fails on iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

When I run my app with google_mobile_ads 0.13.3 in test mode on the iOS simulator, the test ads do not appear, but show the error below:

```
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
flutter: Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 8, domain: com.google.admob, message: Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: xxxxx, mediationAdapterClassName: null, adapterResponses: [AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.DummyAdapter, latencyMillis: 1), description: {
    Credentials =     {
    };
    Error = "Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=8 \"Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags'<…>
flutter: Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 8, domain: com.google.admob, message: Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: yyyyy, mediationAdapterClassName: null, adapterResponses: [AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.DummyAdapter, latencyMillis: 1), description: {
    Credentials =     {
    };
    Error = "Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=8 \"Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flag<…>
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
flutter: Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
flutter: Ad with id `1` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
<Google> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
flutter: Ad with id `0` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
flutter: Ad with id `1` is not available for onAdFailedToLoad.
...
```

I am not sure how "to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting" of my build target.

Any hint on what I might be missing would be appreciated.

Comment: There's an issue on GitHub about this: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/363